# Using setInterval to call a react component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I have created a function called IsLoggedIn that uses a useEffect hook with axios.get to query a server for a user's cookie session time. I would like to call IsLoggedIn using a setInterval function as follows:

```
setInterval(<IsLoggedIn></IsLoggedIn>, 2000) //--> This is in app.js
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    setInterval (async)
eval @ App.js:92
./src/App.js @ bundle.js:75202
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:790
fn @ bundle.js:101
eval @ index.js:6
./src/index.js @ bundle.js:75272
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:790
fn @ bundle.js:101
eval @ client:3
1 @ bundle.js:75389
__webpack_require__ @ bundle.js:790
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:857
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:860
```

Please let me know if anyone has any thoughts on why this is occurring. Thank you!

Comment: simply create a function and write axois in that and invoke that function inside the setInterval

Comment: @MUHAMMADILYAS How would **axios** solve the  issue? It's used to make HTTP requests to external resources.

Comment: @VinaySharma in the question he wants to run http request  in some interval and he is using axios so just telling him to write a function without hook

Comment: @VinaySharma axios.get  in the question and axios is used for http request

Comment: Please read the nature of issue from title correct, it nowhere asks anything about Axios.

Comment: @VinaySharma just read the story behind that what actually he wants

Comment: Please share the code of **IsLoggedIn**.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to fix:

> I have created a function called IsLoggedIn that uses a useEffect hook

Assuming you have created a custom hook, you shouldn't use it as a component(), the correct way would be something like:

```
const bla = useLoggedIn(); // custom hooks are also prefixed with 'use'
```

> I would like to call IsLoggedIn using a setInterval function

hooks can only be called inside function-component's body, so it's best to move the `setInterval` into the `useEffect` of the custom hook.

Answer (score 0):

#### Custom Hooks

It seems what you're calling as a React Component Function is a **Custom Hook**.
Hooks are not components but functions with a mechanism to reuse stateful logic.

**Key points about a custom hook:**

- Can be used only in functional components and not a class component.
- Cannot be used in the form of JSX like `<useFoo />` and need to be called just like any other normal function `useFoo()`.
- As per naming convention, it should always have a `use` prefix followed by the name of functionality, here `useIsLoggedIn`.

You can read more about custom hooks in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) and [rules here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

#### Solution

```
// custom hook to query server for user's cookie session time
const useLoggedIn = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // wrap the entire API call in a setInterval
    setInterval(() => {
      // axios call goes here
      // followed by some other computations
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  // return value (if any)
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  // call the custom hook here instead of JSX
  useLoggedIn();

  return (
    <div>
      {/* rest of JSX */}
    </div>
  );
};
```